# Using yml as a data reference. Bad idea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, yaml

I need about 1,000 words to be able to be accessed constantly by my app. The reason I want it detached is so that down the line, I can dynamically change what those 1,000 words will be.

But I don't necessarily feel this requires a database injection. I feel a simple .yml file could work.

Is this a good practice? And if it is, what would be the best way to do this?

Is it ok to load the 1,000 words in a `before_filter` call ?

Comment: Put them in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think that architecturally this is the right call.

If those are to be changed rarely, then you can put them inside a constants class. If you plan to change them often, what you will do is **write to file system and read from it** which is exactly what every database does, but in a much much faster and optimal way then you could possibly write.

My two cents. Let us know how it worked out.

Comment: I'd only change it once a month, and even that that's entirely optional. I'm thinking that a YML file would work just like an external CD would. You plug in a new CD, you get new words. That's also why I don't want to use the database, because 1,0000 words could be 1200 words, or 900. Each has a `:type`. Would that be architecturally stable writing that crazy long of a hash? Yml just seemed conveniently simple.

Comment: So you would always have no more or no less than ~1000 words, but they would be different from month to month?

Comment: Correct. More like once a user finishes with 1000 words. They can get another 1000 words. But the system always works entirely around those 1000 from the ground up.

Comment: Have you thought about a document oriented database, i.e. MongoDB? It can store exactly what you need, no relations to slow you down, almost instant access to data, fast reads, deletes, etc? Not so hard to setup MongoDB instance nowadays and it works with RoR nicely. And still faster than file system. :)

Take a look:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ruby+Language+Center

Comment: 2 days deep into this. You might have changed my entire life. :D

Comment: :D MongoDB is just the beginning, there are a lot of beautiful, nosql databases out there. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use relational database unless you really need to.  If your "words" are  relatively immutable,  can be accessed simultaneously without multithreadig concerns, you do not need querying etc - they are better off in some hash loaded for entire applications on startup 
loading them for every reuest is not a good idea. 
( this advice is not related to ROR  )